# How to use React-Translate-Component with SELECT-OPTION tag

Tags: reactjs

I am using React-Translate-Component for internationalization , I am trying to use translate inside option values but i get [object Object] instead , Any solution ?

```
 onLangChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState({lang:e.target.value})
    counterpart.setLocale(e.target.value)
}

<select name="yardim" id="yardim" className="selectpicker" data-style="form-control" required>
<option value="1">{<Translate content="iletisim_paragraph1" unsafe={true} component="option" />} 
 </option>
 <option value="2">deg2</option>
 <option value="3">Feedback</option>
 <option value="4">Other</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: i decided to use jsx conditional {lang==="tr" ?<select name="yardim" id="yardim" className="selectpicker" data-style="form-control" required>

 </select>:   <select name="yardim" id="yardim" className="selectpicker" data-style="form-control" required>
"the english one"
 </select>}